# Add line breaks to titles in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm totally a newbie in programming and I'm creating a WordPress site. 
I'm trying to add a line break into a Wordpress title.

I have read a lot and tried a lot but every time I insert a code that was supposed to add a line break, it doesn't break the line and it also stops my WordPress working.
I even asked on Reddit but no one could help.

What do I do to add a line break into a title?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a tutorial site, I'm afraid. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions. The [help] has more details regarding the types of question that are appropriate to ask here. Good luck.

Comment: This question is not clear. If you want help you need to be more specific. Try providing examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

So seems like you would like to add a breakline on every title?!

> If you could, please, would you care to teach me, step by step, how to break a line from the WordPress Title?

If this so, then you need to use a filter:

```
<?php
  function your_custom_filter($title){
       //this function returns the title wrapping div element around it.
       //by default, this should break a line, unless otherwise specified in
       //your css.
       return '<div>' . $title . '</div>';
  }

  add_filter('the_title', 'your_custom_filter');
```

Put that somewhere in your functions.php
The your_custom_filter gets called everytime the_title gets called. We refer to this as [Hooks.](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/)
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try it. You were patient, I was expecting some rant from the community.

Comment: Haha, no problem, we all at one point have started in the beginning.

Comment: @DrDoom, please accept the answer or do an up vote if did helped you.